# How do I test expected Unchecked Exceptions in Kotlin?

Tags: exception, testing, junit, kotlin, unchecked-exception

I am trying to write a test in Kotlin that makes sure an unchecked exception is thrown in specific circumstances.

I am trying to use `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows` like this:

```
assertThrows(MyRuntimeException::class, Executable { myMethodThatThrowsThatException() })
```

when i try this i get a

> Type inference failed compiler error

because my `Exception` in not a `CheckedException` but a `RuntimeException`. Is there any good way to test this behavior without doing the naive try catch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [assertFailsWith](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-fails-with.html) from the Kotlin standard library:

```
assertFailsWith<MyRuntimeException> { myMethodThatThrowsThatException() }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `assertThrows` method expects a `Class` as its first parameter, but you're trying to give it a `KClass`. To fix this, just do the following (as described in the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getclass)):

```
assertThrows(MyRuntimeException::class.java, Executable { myMethodThatThrowsThatException() })
```

You can also leave out the explicit `Executable` type:

```
assertThrows(MyRuntimeException::class.java, { myMethodThatThrowsThatException() })
```

Or if your method really doesn't take any parameters, you can use a method reference to it:

```
assertThrows(MyRuntimeException::class.java, ::myMethodThatThrowsThatException)
```